# mysql high cpu usage (no have slow queries)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql. MYSQL High CPU Usage (300%-400%). But I cannot find solution to handle it. I optimized config mysql.
I think maybe my server has a problem, but What do I need to do to find the problem and how to fix it.

Infomation:

- Server not have slow queries
- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; => Only 7 connection (not lock).
- show engine innodb status => ROW OPERATIONS

```
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
5 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=25898, Main thread ID=140213805094656, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 16646, updated 89843, deleted 48, read 45381116563
0.50 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 2140759.81 reads/s
```

- mysqld.log have so many line as (it happens continuously once every second):

```
Access denied for user 'test'@'139.198.168.221' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'root'@'139.198.168.221' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'218.59.174.83' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'mysqld'@'218.59.174.83' (using password: NO)
Access denied for user 'root'@'180.215.129.37' (using password: NO)
Access denied for user 'server'@'112.121.189.218' (using password: NO)
[Warning] Host name 'zg-0416b-112.stretchoid.com' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
[Warning] Host name 'zg-0416a-245.stretchoid.com' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

Comment: scan of open orts are very common, that is why databases usually allow only access from localhost, bedides firewall and itrusin detection solutions, which willnot prevent any attempt, but stilla re better than an open mysql server. Can you not switch to only allowing  access via vpn or ssh?

Comment: What is the value of `long_query_time`?  (Lower it)  Is the slowlog file being written to at all?

Comment: Do you know where those IP addresses are located?  Is there a monitoring service?  What about hackers?

Comment: Let's see the PROCESSLIST.  No locks is mostly irrelevant when chasing CPU issues.

Comment: stretchoid.com is godaddy -- does that ring any bells?

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for support, My IP is located in VietNam, It is not related to godaddy. long_query_time is default = 10. I close port 3306 and CPU Mysql reduced.

Comment: @nbk, Thank for support. I installed Fail2Ban to filter port 3306 (it block so many IP)

Comment: Lower `long_query_time` to `1`, restart, and then the slowlog might catch something.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody is trying to hack your server using bots (all these log entries are login attempts). To be honest I see the same atempts in my logs all the time. To check if this is the source of your server overload (I am not sure...) try to restrict network connections to mySQL: uncomment this line in your **mysqld.cnf**

```
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart your mySQL and check the load.

Comment: that is a normal log, so no hacking attempt was tried. but there are scans all the time. i think it is a goof idea to let only localhost acces to the database, but as you have mysql force to allow access from everywhere, it was made intentionally.

Comment: I agree scans are not "hacking" but usually looking for a way to do so... Access from everywhere in most cases is not a must. It is just an easiest way to manage your server. So it can be a good starting point to check 'bind-address'.

Comment: Thank @IgorPigin, I closed port 3306, and CPU is reduced